# XLST 1.0 Split node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to split this node at `<foo>`:

```
  <p>
    <span>This is before foo.</span>
    <foo>inside foo</foo>
    <span>This is after foo.</span>
  </p>
```

The result I want is

```
  <p>
    <span>This is before foo.</span>
  </p>
  <foo>inside foo</foo>
  <p>
    <span>This is after foo.</span>
  </p>
```

But I'm getting

```
  <p>
    <span>This is before foo.</span>
    <p>
      <span>This is before foo.</span>
    </p>
    <foo>inside foo</foo>
    <p>
      <span>This is after foo.</span>
    </p>
    <span>This is after foo.</span>
  </p>
```

And here's the style sheet I'm trying with:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/foo">
        <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::node()"/>
        </xsl:element>

        <foo>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </foo>

        <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

How can I get rid of that extra output?

Edit: Gave a more realistic example. See http://xsltransform.net/pNP88xQ/2

Comment: This is a completely different question from the one before the edit. Can there be more than one `foo` element in a `p`?

Comment: More than one foo: That hasn't occured to me, but yes it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***-- edited in response to your edited question --***

This is not an easy task to accomplish in XSLT 1.0 (it's much easier to do in XSLT 2.0 using `xsl:for-each-group`).

One possible approach is a method known as *sibling recursion*:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <!-- start sibling recursion -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- first node in a group -->
<xsl:template match="p/node()[not(self::foo)]">
    <p>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <!-- collect the following node in this group -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::foo)]" mode="collect"/>
    </p>
    <!-- continue recursion with the following divider -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::foo[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- other nodes in a group -->
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="collect">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <!-- collect the following node in this group -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::foo)]" mode="collect"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <!-- restart sibling recursion -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No sorry, that gives ```<p>
   <p>before </p>
   <foo>inside</foo>
   <p> after</p>
</p>``` Also, my example is simplified, the "before" and "after" parts can contain child nodes.

Comment: No, that is not the result received by applying  the above - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbeZ Also, other nodes **are** preserved - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbeZ/1

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. However, I realize I indeed oversimplified my example. I've edited my original post with a more realistic one. Sorry for the confusion.